# How to query a ScriptDB database for key:values within objects nested in array objects Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, javascript-objects

Assume an object *schema* stored in ScriptDb:

```
{name: 'alice',
 age:  12,
 interests: [
     {interest: 'tea parties', enthusiasm: 'high'},
     {interest: 'croquet', enthusiasm: 'moderate'},         
 ]
}
```

I understand how to query against the first two *attributes* but not how to run a query to return all *rows* where `interests[enthusiasm = moderate]`

Taking that example literally and trying: `db.query({interests:[{enthusiasm: 'moderate'}]});`
returns a **ScriptDbResult** but any attempt to use that result's methods results in an error:

```
Queries can only contain letters, numbers, spaces, dashes and underscores as keys.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible. It may be supported in a future update. The best you can do now is load all interests and loop through them yourself.

Comment: Corey, do you advise that open an enhancement request regarding this?

Comment: Thanks. Issue opened: [1733: Allow query in ScriptDb within objects nested in arrays](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1733)